# on click button enable and disable input to edit tr using jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an edit button at the end of the tr tag first I want to disable input type checkbox in the table and then onclick I want to edit that tr with all input type check box will be enable to edit then when I click on edit again then it will disable again the idea is to edit tr on edit click
please suggest me the suitable code for this here is my code.

```
<table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                            <thead>
                        <tr style="background-color:#d2d6de;border:2px ridge gray;">
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Name</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Post</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Content Moderation</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Money Manager</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Parking Manager</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Notify User</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">User Moderation</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Facility Manager</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Asset Manager</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Move In Move Out</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Handling Issues</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Inventory</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Visitors</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Can Add/Edit Committee Members</td>
                                <td class="mailbox-name">Action</td>
                            </font>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                            while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){

                    ?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" style="padding-top:25px;"><b><?php echo $row["FirstName"] . " " . $row["LastName"];?></b></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" style="padding-top:30px;"><?php echo $row["role"];?></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>
                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><center style="padding-top:20px;"><input type="checkbox" class="cheakedit"></center></td>


                    <td class="mailbox-name" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>" style="widht:20px;"><center><button  class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" id="<?php echo $row["Id"]; ?>"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i></button><div style="height:3px;"></div><button class="btn btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button></center></td>
            </tr>    
                <?php } ?>

                </tbody>
                    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deepakb/ezgtaodv/9/).

**HTML**

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><span class="edit">Edit</span></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><span class="edit">Edit</span></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><span class="edit">Edit</span></td>
  </tr>
   <tr>
   <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" disabled></td>
    <td><span class="edit">Edit</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$(function() {
   $( "table" ).on( "click", ".edit", function() {
      $(this).removeClass('edit');
      $(this).addClass('removeEdit');
        $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', false);
        });

    $( "table" ).on( "click", ".removeEdit", function() {
      $(this).removeClass('removeEdit');
      $(this).addClass('edit');
        $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('disabled', true);
        });
});
```

Hope this is what you need!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you use [jQuery.ToggleClass()](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) to toggle a class on your button. Then you can have a check in your click() function that sees the current class and applies your wanted functionality.

```
$(".myBtn").click(function(){
  $(this).toggleClass("editmode");
    if($(this).hasClass("editmode")){
      alert("Is in editmode")
    } else{
      alert("is not in editmode");
   }
);
```

This really basic [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8cce7jdq/2/) can visualize it.